# Unity shader to render objects with same material to subsequent GrabPasses

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, blur, masking

## Overview

I'm working on a shader in Unity 2017.1 to enable [UnityEngine.UI.Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Image.html) components to blur what is behind them.

As some of the approaches in [this Unity forum topic](https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-dynamic-blurred-background-on-ui.345083/), I use [GrabPasses](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-GrabPass.html), specifically a `tex2Dproj(_GrabTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(<uv with offset>))` call to look up the pixels that I use in my blur summations. I'm doing a basic 2-pass box blur, and not looking to optimize performance right now.

This works as expected:
[image]

I also want to mask the blur effect based on the image alpha. I use `tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uvmain)` to look up the alpha color of the sprite on the pixel I am calculating the blur for, which I then combine with the alpha of the blur.

This works fine when working with just a single `UI.Image` object:
[image]

### The Problem

However when I have multiple `UI.Image` objects that share the same Material created from this shader, images layered above will cut into the images below:
[image]

I believe this is because objects with the same material may be drawn simultaneously and so don't appear in each other's GrabPasses, or at least something to that effect.

That at least would explain why, if I duplicate the material and use each material on its own object, I don't have this problem.

Here is the source code for the shader: https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/8d0f531b815dfad07823d44bc12b8112

### The Question

Is there a way to force objects of the same material to draw consecutively and not in parallel? Basically, I would like the result of a lower object's render passes to be visible to the grab pass of subsequent objects.

I could imagine creating a component that dynamically instantiates materials to force this, or using render textures, but I would really like a solution that doesn't require adding components or creating multiple materials to swap out.

I would love a solution that is entirely self-contained within one shader/one material but is unsure if this is possible. I'm still only starting to get familiar with shaders so I'm positive there are some features I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it was me re-drawing what I grabbed from the `_GrabTexture` that was causing the the issue. By correctly handling the alpha logic there I was able to get exactly the desired behavior:

[image]

Here is the updated sourcecode: https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/7d62f282705169a2855a0aac315ff381

As mentioned before, optimizing the convolution step was not my priority.